# Emulator in android studio starting in sidebar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I had some problems with the emulator and when i tried to solve this, by mistake i made the emulator start only from sidebar. I kept googleing how to get it back to normal, but i couldn't get it done.

Here is a photo of how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 34):

Go to File>Settings>Tools>Emulator and uncheck the "Launch in a tool window":

[image: See picture attached]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Restart in Go to File>Settings>Tools>Emulator and uncheck the "Launch in a tool window":

Sucess